# How can an Ember-data PromiseArray be rejected?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have a list of a couple thousand people that has a search and filter functionality.  The search box is doing a google like search as you type and there is a drop down to filter by the person's status.  If you select the drop down and start typing quickly sometimes the results do not come back in the same order and the last one to return is rendered without the status filter, or without the search.

I would like to reject the previous promise if it is still pending any time a new search is fired.  The problem is, the last search is being stored as a PromiseArray, which I can call reject on, but it does not seem to actually reject the promise.

I am using ember 1.5.1 and ember-data 1.0.0.beta.7 on ember-cli 0.0.28

Here is the generated person search controller:

```
Controller = Em.ArrayController.extend({
  lastFetchedPage: 1,
  searchTerms: "",
  isFreshSearch: false,
  statusToFilterBy: null,

  statuses: (Em.computed(function() {
    return this.get("store").find("status");
  })).property(),

  statusToFilterByDidChange: (function() {
    return this.conductSearch();
  }).observes("statusToFilterBy"),

  searchTermsDidChange: (function() {
    this.haltCurrentSearch();
    this.set("searchTermsDirty", true);
    return Em.run.debounce(this, this.conductSearch, 750);
  }).observes("searchTerms"),

  conductSearch: function() {
    this.set("lastFetchedPage", 1);
    this.set("isFreshSearch", true);
    return this.fetchPeople();
  },

  haltCurrentSearch: function() {
    if (this.get("currentSearch.isPending")) {
      this.get("currentSearch").reject(new Error("Terms outdated"));
    }
  },

  fetchPeople: function() {
    var search;
    search = this.get("store").find("person-summary", {
      page: this.get("lastFetchedPage"),
      terms: this.get("searchTerms"),
      status_id: this.get("statusToFilterBy.id")
    });
    search.then((function(_this) {
      return function(personSummaries) {
        return _this.displayResults(personSummaries);
      };
    })(this));
    this.set("currentSearch", search);
    return this.set("searchTermsDirty", false);
  },

  displayResults: function(personSummaries) {
    if (this.get("isFreshSearch")) {
      this.set("isFreshSearch", false);
      return this.set("model", personSummaries);
    } else {
      return personSummaries.forEach((function(_this) {
        return function(personSummary) {
          return _this.get("model").addRecord(personSummary);
        };
      })(this));
    }
  }

  bottomVisibleChanged: function(person) {
    if (person === this.get("lastPerson")) {
      this.incrementProperty("lastFetchedPage");
      return this.fetchPeople();
    }
  },

  lastPerson: (Em.computed(function() {
    var people;
    people = this.get("model.content");
    return people[people.length - 1];
  })).property("model.@each")
});
```

Comment: You can't reject a promise from outside. You can try to cancel it.